# How to create a textbox with two lines in html - placeholder being intact

Tags: html

[image: Please see the image with two line in the text box one being place holder]

I want to create a textbox like the image attached in HTML, JS. Please share some Ideas.

In the image you can see 3 cases

Top - Successful Case

Middle - Default when phone number is empty Textbox is shown with placeholder PHONE NUMBER

Bottom-Place holder shows up on top while user enters the phone number

Comment: Why show the three cases; do you only want answers on the first one?

Comment: I have shown three cases to show the state of the Text box. I am looking for Ideas

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, you need JQuery to do that...

```js
var placeholder = 'This is a line \nthis should be a new line';
$('textarea').attr('value', placeholder);

$('textarea').focus(function(){
    if($(this).val() === placeholder){
        $(this).attr('value', '');
    }
});

$('textarea').blur(function(){
    if($(this).val() ===''){
        $(this).attr('value', placeholder);
    }    
});
```

```css
textarea{
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    color:gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>

<textarea></textarea>
```

Source:http://jsfiddle.net/airandfingers/pdXRx/247/

Comment: First belong the text as value then blur it when textarea not clicked on ... you can delete one of the textareas (or add more), this way worked on all browsers

Comment: Answer you have given doesn't need any Jquery ! Just use placeholder in bootstrap <input type="textarea" class="form-control" id="inputname" placeholder="BLABLABLA"> My question is different. I am trying to built a textbox with one placeholder and another value which a user will enter. (Place holder should be visible all the time)

Answer (score 0):

## Example 1

I have an example that can help you understand this question you made.

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app>
  <label for="pN">Phone number:</label>
  <input id="pN" type="text" value="1-800-CALL-MOM"></input>
<div style="height: 10px; border-bottom: 1px dotted silver;margin-bottom: 10px;"></div>

<div class="wrapper">PhoneNumberToDisplay: <div id="out1"></div></div>

<div class="wrapper">Letters Converted: <div id="out2"></div></div>

<div class="wrapper">PhoneNumberToDial: <div id="out3"></div></div>


  <div id="out4"></div>
  <div id="out3"></div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
* { font-family: sans-serif; padding: 4px; }
#out1,#out2,#out3 { color: #999; display: inline-block;}
#out1 {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var phoneLetterToDigit = ['2','2','2','3','3','3','4','4','4','5','5','5','6','6','6','7','7','7','7','8','8','8','9','9','9','9'];

var raw = '';
var digitsReplaced = '';
var numbersOnly = '';

$('#pN').keyup(function () {
  update();
});

function update() {
  raw = $("#pN").val();
  digitsReplaced = '';

  $.each(raw.split(''), function(a,b) {
    var l = b.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0) - 65;

    if (l >= 0 && l <= 25) {
       digitsReplaced += phoneLetterToDigit[l];
    }
    else {
      digitsReplaced += b;
    }
  });

  numbersOnly = digitsReplaced.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,'');

  $("#out1").html(raw);
  $("#out2").html(digitsReplaced);
  $("#out3").html(numbersOnly);
}

update();
```

You can see the behavior here:

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/FMCalisto/pu2q571s/)

Comment: Sorry This is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

## Example 2

I want to try again to help you with another code example.

**HTML**

```
<h1>Phone field scrubbing utility</h1>

<ul>
    <li>Enter any content (characters, puntuation, etc.)</li>
    <li>As long as there are 10 digits it will validate true</li>
    <li>Providing the first digit is not 0 or 1</li>
    <li>And providing there is not 1 digit repeated 10 times</li>
    <li>The &quot;format it&quot; button will do just that</li>
    <li>The &quot;submit it&quot; button will strip out everything but digits</li>
</ul>

<input class="phone" id="phone1" value="XXXXXXXXXX"><br>
<input class="phone" id="phone1" value="XXXXXXXXXX"><br>
<input class="phone" id="phone1" value="XXXXXXXXXX"><br>
<input type="button" id="format" value="format it">
<input type="button" id="submit" value="submit it">
```

**CSS**

```
body{
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 25px;
}
input{
    font-size: xx-large; 
    border: 2px solid #555;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.on{
    border: 2px dashed #555;
/*  background: rgba(255, 215, 0,.15);
    color: rgb(255, 215, 0);*/
}
.goodClass{
    /*border: 1px solid rgb(0, 255, 0);*/
    background: rgba(0, 255, 0, .15);
    color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
}
.badClass{
    /*border: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);*/
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0,.15);
    color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function(){
    $('#phone1').phoneScrubber({
            focusClass: 'on',
            goodClass: 'goodClass',
            badClass: 'badClass',
            testOnKeyup: true
    });

    $.fn.phoneScrubber.formatAll();

    $('#format').click(function(){
        $.fn.phoneScrubber.formatAll();
    });

    $('#submit').click(function(){
        if($.fn.phoneScrubber.validateAll()){
            $.fn.phoneScrubber.submitAll();
        }
    });
});

(function($) {
    $.fn.phoneScrubber = function(opts) {

        var
        obj = this,
            defaults = {
                    phoneCleaner    : /\D/g 
                    , repeated      : /(.)\1{9,}/g
                    , minLen        : 10
                    , omit          : [0, 1]
                    , format        : '() -'
                    , focusClass    : null
                    , testOnKeyup   : true
                    , goodClass     : null
                    , badClass      : null
                    , formatOnBlur  : false
            }, settings = $.extend({}, defaults, opts)
                    , testStr
                    , aFormat   = settings.format.split('')
                    , pre1      = aFormat[0]
                    , pre2      = aFormat[1] + aFormat[2]
                    , sep       = aFormat[3]
                    , message   = ''
                    , part1     = ''
                    , part2     = ''
                    , part3     = ''
                    , returnVal = ''
                    , setVal
                    , test
                    , cleanIt
                    , formatNumber
                    , cleanNumber
                    , errCount  = 0
                    , errs      = []
                    ;

        return this.each(function() {

            test = function(dirty) {
                var test        = dirty.replace(settings.phoneCleaner,'')
                    , testLen   = test.length
                    , startChar = parseInt(test.substring(0,1))
                    , testStr   = test.substring(0,10)

                if(testLen < settings.minLen){
                    // message = 'invalid length: '+testLen;
                    // alert(message);
                    return false;
                }

                if(settings.omit.indexOf(startChar)!==-1){
                    // message = 'First character cannot be '+startChar;
                    // alert(message);
                    return false;
                }

                if(testStr.match(settings.repeated)){
                    // message = "Nice try... repeated characters";
                    // alert(message);
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }

            cleanIt = function(dirty){
                return dirty.replace(settings.phoneCleaner,'');
            }         

            $.fn.phoneScrubber.formatNumber = function(dirty) {
                var clean = cleanIt(dirty);
                clean = clean.substring(0, settings.minLen)
                part1 = clean.substring(0,3);
                part2 = clean.substring(3,6);
                part3 = clean.substring(6,10);

                returnVal = pre1+part1+pre2+part2+sep+part3;
                return returnVal;
            }

            $.fn.phoneScrubber.cleanNumber = function(dirty) {
                var clean = cleanIt(dirty);
                clean = clean.substring(0, settings.minLen)
                return clean;
            }

            $.fn.phoneScrubber.formatAll = function(){
                obj.each(function(){
                    var $this = $(this);
                    if(test($this.val())){
                        $this.val($.fn.phoneScrubber.formatNumber($this.val()));
                    }
                });
            }

            $.fn.phoneScrubber.validateAll = function(){

                var returnVal = true;

                errs = [];

                obj.each(function(){
                    if (test($(this).val())==false){
                        returnVal = false;
                        errs.push(this);
                    }
                });
                return returnVal;
            }

            $.fn.phoneScrubber.getErrFields = function(){
                return errs;
            }

            $.fn.phoneScrubber.submitAll = function(){
                obj.each(function(){
                    var $this = $(this);
                    if(test($this.val())){
                        $this.val($.fn.phoneScrubber.cleanNumber($this.val()));
                    }
                });
            }

            obj.focus(function() {
                $(this).addClass(settings.focusClass);
            })
                .keyup(function() {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    if(settings.testOnKeyup){
                        if(test($this.val())){
                            // good
                            $this
                                .removeClass(settings.badClass)
                                .addClass(settings.goodClass);
                        }else{
                            // bad
                            $this
                                .removeClass(settings.goodClass)
                                .addClass(settings.badClass);
                        }
                    }
            })
                .blur(function() {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    $this.removeClass(settings.focusClass);
                    if(test($this.val())){
                        if(settings.formatOnBlur){
                            $this.val(formatNumber($this.val()));
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

The Source Code: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/FMCalisto/dchrgvt1/)

Comment: I appreciate your effort, But I think you didn't follow my question. I am looking for a Textbox with a placeholder that always stays while we input any text. (Its not about validation). Please see the screen shot closely to understand

Answer (score 0):

## Example 3

I hope to finally help you on this.

**HTML**

```
<textarea class='autoExpand' rows='3' data-min-rows='3' placeholder='Auto-Expanding Textarea'></textarea>

<textarea class='autoExpand' rows='3' data-min-rows='3' placeholder='Auto-Expanding Textarea'></textarea>

<textarea class='autoExpand' rows='3' data-min-rows='3' placeholder='Auto-Expanding Textarea'></textarea>
```

**CSS**

```
body{ background:#728EB2; }

textarea{  
  display:block;
  box-sizing: padding-box;
  overflow:hidden;

  padding:10px;
  width:250px;
  font-size:14px;
  margin:50px auto;
  border-radius:8px;
  border:6px solid #556677;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document)
    .one('focus.textarea', '.autoExpand', function(){
        var savedValue = this.value;
        this.value = '';
        this.baseScrollHeight = this.scrollHeight;
        this.value = savedValue;
    })
    .on('input.textarea', '.autoExpand', function(){
        var minRows = this.getAttribute('data-min-rows')|0,
             rows;
        this.rows = minRows;
    console.log(this.scrollHeight , this.baseScrollHeight);
        rows = Math.ceil((this.scrollHeight - this.baseScrollHeight) / 17);
        this.rows = minRows + rows;
    });
```

This time I try to make as you said.

Source Code: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/FMCalisto/8urpv3kL/)